# Input doesn't change using this code in the console

Tags: javascript, html, console, dom-manipulation

beginner here :)

I'm trying to code a script which will take an input from an HTML form and display the text that a user types in on the screen, using JS in Chrome's console.
I have the following code:

```
var h1 = document.createElement('h1')
h1.innerText = "Type into the input to make this text change"

var input = document.createElement('input')
input.setAttribute('type', 'text')

document.body.innerText = '';
document.body.appendChild(h1);
document.body.appendChild(input);
```

The input work and I can type any kind of text in there.
However, the h1 won't change with the text from the input.

Can you please share your thoughts on why you think this isn't working?

Thank you.

Comment: There's no code anywhere that a) reacts to the input being typed into b) attempts to change the h1's text? All your code does is create the two elements and put them into <body>.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an `input` event listener for the `input` element, and change the `h1` value depending on `input` value.

```
var h1 = document.createElement('h1')
h1.innerText = "Type into the input to make this text change"

var input = document.createElement('input')
input.addEventListener('input', (e) => {
   h1.textContent = e.target.value
})
input.setAttribute('type', 'text')

document.body.innerText = '';
document.body.appendChild(h1);
document.body.appendChild(input);
```